# CSS Hover Image for widget area in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, widget, hover

I am trying to create a CSS hover image to be used in a wordpress widget. I have created the files in Fireworks and exported part of the CSS, but now I am completely stuck on where to put it, and what I am missing.

Here is the code generated by Fireworks:

```
.e3circles{ background:url("e3circles.png") top left no-repeat; }
.icons_equity_symb{ width:287px; height:289px; background-position:-10px -10px; }
.icons_equity_symb_1{ width:287px; height:289px; background-position:-307px -10px; }
.icons_energy_symb{ width:300px; height:289px; background-position:-604px -10px; }
.icons_energy_symb_1{ width:300px; height:289px; background-position:-914px -10px; }
.icons_easy_symb{ width:313px; height:289px; background-position:-1224px -10px; }
.icons_easy_symb_1{ width:313px; height:289px; background-position:-1547px -10px; }
.icons_pop{ width:900px; height:289px; background-position:-1870px -10px; }
.icons_pop_1{ width:900px; height:289px; background-position:-2780px -10px; }
```

The image can be seen at: http://rachelorovio.com/sprites/e3circles.png

I started off using the theme Minimum from Studio Press which has the circle social media icons: http://demo.studiopress.com/minimum/

My client wants to keep the circles, but we had to switch to the theme Executive for other reasons.

I have researched this for several days now, and it seems the more I learn the more complicated it becomes. Every script is different, so I can’t even compare them side by side. Please let me know if you can help!! Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to enqueue script http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script in your theme/functions.php?  Or if you are creating your own plugin/widget you could also add it to the plugin directly. https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin

Answer (score 0):

so the simple way is to use a plugin, you can try widget css classes :

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/widget-css-classes/

Otherwise open your theme, add another style2.css for example to your theme and add the Code on it, open header.php and link to this style.. then go to your dashboard, add a TEXT Widget and Call the Div where this Circles will appear...

Goodluck